# How can I prevent Nautilus from showing search results?

Tags: nautilus, search

**How can I prevent Nautilus from showing search results?**

First this is not for hiding .. you know.

I want to hide my MMORPG so I am the only that can play it. Is there a script, command, anything that can make nautilus stop from showing the results.

e.g. : Someone searched for a keyword and yes nautilus is searching for it, How can I fool that he/she that nautilus is going to show the result, but keep the result hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Re-name the program to something nobody would ever touch, "IE10 T/Wine"? LOL.

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: If I am going to do that then, I have to rename it before after using it. And that's funny.